# Changing Icon in Sap.m.tree having CustomTreeItem

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have an sap.m.tree control and I am using CustomTreeItem I want to change the default arrow icon on the left side please refer to the [Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrRGm.png).

Comment: Do you really want to change the standard icons for opening and closing a tree node, or do you want to add an icon to existing entries, like so: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TreeIcon/preview

I think you can only change the standard icon by implementing some custom css, but be aware that this could negatively influence the responsiveness of the layout.

Comment: In this [link](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3684608) it's done by extending the panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the below statements in Init Method ( at view level or component/app Level) and change the icons to whatever you need. I changed the default icons to Plus and Minus.

```
        sap.m.TreeItemBase.prototype.ExpandedIconURI = sap.ui.core.IconPool.getIconURI("less");
        sap.m.TreeItemBase.prototype.CollapsedIconURI = sap.ui.core.IconPool.getIconURI("add");
```

Let me know if you need more info.